# jQuery selector with data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to implement a jQuery selector which selects all the elements with data-xy-* attributes. I know how to select elements if we know the complete data attribute:

`$("[data-xy-a]")` will give me all the elements which have a data attribute `data-xy-a`

My problem is that the element can have any value instead of `a`. I want something like:

```
$("[data-xy-*]")
```

Comment: I can get a list of data attributes with `.data()` but I need elements with `data-xy-*` attributes. Yes, I can iterate through the `.data()` list and check for keys starting with `xy`, but is there any other simple solution?

Comment: @DvS: Because I'm not selecting on the basis of value. I'm looking for selecting on a custom key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no selector for this (as far as I know) but you can filter them out yourself...

```
$.expr[':'].dataStartsWith = function (elem, index, not) {
  var data = $(elem).data();
  return Object.keys(data).some(function (key) {
    return key.indexOf(not[3]) === 0;
  });
};

$(':dataStartsWith("xy")');
```

Just bear in mind data attribute names are converted to camelcase in dataset so to match `data-xy-z-*` you will need to use `$(':dataStartsWith("xyZ")');`

Comment: Seems like I have to use my own function as a selector then